# XML-RPC library for Windows Store Apps

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro, xml-rpc, windows-store-apps

I need XML-RPC library that I can use with Windows Store Apps (aka Metro). As far as I know there is a only XML-RPC.NET library for .NET and it doesn't support Windows Store Apps.

Is there a other way besides constructing and parsing XML-RPC request and response manually ?